# Select2 tags multi selector looks odd in Safari

Tags: css, safari, frontend, jquery-select2

See image below. The selector looks right in Chrome. I've tried taking the selector out of surrounding containers to no avail.

It's defined like this:

```
<select id="videoAvailableCountriesSelector" name="tags" selected="{{videoAvailable}}" multi tags></select>
```

Any help is very much appreciated. I'm using select2 version 4.0.3 (the latest).

[image]